# Invoke listeners on JComponents with default text when program starts

Tags: java, listener

I have several `JTextFields` in my Frame, and `CaretListeners` on each one (maybe I shouldn't be using `CaretListeners`?). As I click on or modify the text fields (after the program has started), I can step through the debugger and see the `CaretListener` being invoked properly.

**My situation:**

*I have default text in some of them, and I would like to update other variables based on said default text when the program first starts.*

**My question:**

*How can I invoke these listeners when the program first starts? With my current code, I have to explicitly click the `JTextField` to invoke the listener.*

```
    my_txtfield = new JTextField();
    my_txtfield.setText("prime_numbers.rsc");
    my_txtfield.addCaretListener(e -> {
        if (my_txtfield.getText().equals("")) key_gen.rsc_filename = null;
        else key_gen.rsc_filename = my_txtfield.getText();
    });
```

I also tried moving the `.setText()` line after the listener lambda, but that won't do it either.

[here's a picture snippit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhGIe.png)

Comment: Better you do it when you instantiate your listener rather than explicitely calling your listener.

Comment: @SMA, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a timer, and check that way. (javax.swing.Timer;)

```
  ActionListener doThis = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       // check the JTextFields in here.
       ...
    }
}
```

};
`Timer tim = new Timer(1000,doThis);
tim.start();`